# Unable to pull one item of data from the Open Weather Map api using JSON

Tags: json

all.

This is a test to see if I can connect to the Open Weather Map api and successfully display an item of data from it (for now I am just trying to get the city name for a given latitude and longitude).

I am doing this inside a CodePen pen, by the way.

The problem is that nothing appears on the page - I get no city name at all.

What is this missing? (I have obscured my api key)

```
<html><body>
<div class="Text-center">
        <h1> Local Weather</h1>
        <h3>Front End Dev Project</h3>
    <ul class ="list-unstyled">
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="city"></li>
    </ul>
<div>
</body></html>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var long= -77.0506895;
  var lat = 38.8925157; 
  var api =  'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherlat='+lat+'&lon'+long+'=&appid=(HIDDEN)';

    $.getJSON(api, function(data){
       var city = data.name;
       $("#city").html(city);  
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct url, please correct your url

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid={AppKey}

and the response below

```
{
   "coord":{
      "lon":138.93,
      "lat":34.97
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":800,
         "main":"Clear",
         "description":"clear sky",
         "icon":"01n"
      }
   ],
   "base":"cmc stations",
   "main":{
      "temp":297.374,
      "pressure":1018.36,
      "humidity":93,
      "temp_min":297.374,
      "temp_max":297.374,
      "sea_level":1027.9,
      "grnd_level":1018.36
   },
   "wind":{
      "speed":7.46,
      "deg":243.504
   },
   "clouds":{
      "all":0
   },
   "dt":1467816873,
   "sys":{
      "message":0.0045,
      "country":"JP",
      "sunrise":1467747404,
      "sunset":1467799281
   },
   "id":1851632,
   "name":"Shuzenji",
   "cod":200
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I changed the URL to exactly what you have stated with the exception that I inserted my key. However the name of the city ("Shuzenji") is still not showing up on the page.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the following works OUTSIDE of CodePen. If I use it inside CodePen, it is blocking the JSON call somehow. If I run this however in Chrome from a version written in NotePad, it returns "Shuzenji" just fine.

But that is an issue for another thread.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var api = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=52481ca8a499564783f5f082863acac1';
    $.getJSON(api, function(data){
       var city = data.name;
       $("#city").html(city);  
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Text-center">
        <h1> Local Weather</h1>
        <h3>Front End Dev Project</h3>
    <ul class ="list-unstyled">
        <li class="btn btn-default" id="city"></li>
    </ul>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```